# Need to show modal until multiple TinyMCE inits finished completely

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am loading several TinyMCE editors, with separate init() like so:

```
tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'.classOne',
    plugins: "pagebreak, code, image",
    toolbar: "pagebreak, code, image",
    relative_urls: false,
    pagebreak_separator: "<!-- page break -->",
    image_list: function(success){
        apiCall( { 
            method: "GET", 
            url: "/api/get/filelist/folder",
            data: '', 
            success: function(data) { success(JSON.parse(data.payload)); }
        } );
    }
});
```

There are several, one for each ".classOne" or ".classTwo", etc. Everything is fine, except I'm trying to pop a "Please wait" modal (using Bootstrap, BTW) until they all finish setting up. Modal pops, but goes away fast (I know why, and it's not this problem,it's just going away because the code fires before the tiny editor is all setup), and I can see the "Waiting for rainmaker.tiny.cloud..." in the lower left corner for several seconds longer. It's loading for each editor, and there are many, maybe 20-100 sometimes.

UX ends up being that they might try to click on a link (that unhides the editor for that specific section) before it is actually available.

Is there a way for me to tell TinyMCE init to call a specific function once the editor is fully loaded? I looked at the callbacks on the site and didn't see/understand success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE 3/4/5 all have a method called init_instance_callback, which fires when the editor is ready to go. See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback

For your use case I would resolve a promise inside that callback, eg: classOnePromise.resolve(editor)

And use a Promise.All([ classOnePromise, ... ]).then(hideModal) to hide the model, when all promises have resolved.

Hope that helps

Ekim

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I had to change hte modal "show" code to: setup: function(editor) 
        {
            showWaitingModal('initTinyMceExecutiveSummary');
        },